How to draw to screen in x86 Assembly?
I am trying to code a game in x86 Assembly. I don't know how to draw to screen using x86 assembly.
Based on my previous experience with assembly I assume I have to code a bootloader which jumps to a label that triggers a bios interrupt to draw to the screen.
I don't know what bios interrupt to trigger and how.

You tagged this [linux].  Do you want to write a program that runs under Linux, perhaps running full-screen on a virtual console, e.g. drawing on the framebuffer?  Or under X11 or Wayland (so you can run it without switching away from your graphical desktop or window manager)?  If the latter, you'd want to use a library; using socket / read / write system calls to talk to the X11 server would be a lot of code to write vs. calling Xlib functions.

But you're also talking about writing a legacy bootloader that use IBM-PC BIOS calls in 16 bit mode.  If that's what you want to write, remove the [linux] tag.

It'd be better to avoid the whole legacy bootloader part and write for UEFI and/or GRUB if you can.  8086 so isn't worth the trouble anymore, unless you're stuck on ancient hardware.

If you want "raw" (no operating system, not even DOS) access to the hardware, like the graphics card, you're in the realm of device-driver programming and device-specific code. For a "pure" learning experience - and something that is not unlikely to work from bootloader code for even recent PC-style hardware - you can try programming the graphics "as if it were VGA".
A good reference for this is the OSDev wiki, https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware for VGA specifically.
